# Evalute $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \cos (tx) \, dx$

Tags: analysis

I can't solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \cos (tx) \, dx.$

Thank you very much!

Comment: is this $\cos(tx)$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Do you know that on this site, we do appreciate that questions come together with some personal  sentences like "I have tried this...", "I am blocked there" ? Otherwise your question could be closed...

Comment: Yes, $\cos(tx)$

Comment: Are you sure of the question ? Do you know Bessel's function ?

Comment: Maybe a trig sub?

Comment: Can this problem solve by elementary method?

Comment: Without your giving context, nobody can really know what you consider "elementary". Maybe you're a curious ten-years-old, how can we possibly know?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on tools acquired in a first course in calculus.  However, we begin with a primer on Bessel functions, a topic not typically introduced in elementary calculus.

---

---

> **PRIMER $1$:**

The Bessel Function, $J_n(t)$, of the first kind and of integer order $n$ can be defined as

$$J_n(t)=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \cos(nx-t\sin(x))\,dx \tag{P1}$$

Then, the zeroth order Bessel function, $J_0(t)$ is expressed as

$$\begin{align}
J_0(t)&=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \cos(t\sin(x))\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(t\sin(x))\,dx+\frac1\pi\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(t\sin(x))\,dx\tag{P2}\\\\
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(t\sin(x))\,dx\tag{P3}
\end{align}$$

where we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$ in the second integral of $(\text{P}2)$ to arrive at $(\text{P}3)$.

---

> **PRIMER $2$:**

The derivative of $J_0(t)$, is

$$\begin{align}
J_0'(t)&=-\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sin(t\sin(x))\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_0^\pi \cos(x-t\sin(x))\,dx-\int_0^\pi \cos(x+t\sin(x))\,dx\right)\tag{P4}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_0^\pi \cos(x-t\sin(x))\,dx+\int_0^\pi \cos(x-t\sin(x))\,dx\right)\tag{P5}\\\\
&=-J_1(t)\tag{P6}
\end{align}$$

where we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$ in the second integral of $(\text{P}4)$ to arrive at $(\text{P}5)$.

---

---

Let $f$ be given by the integral

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\,(t\cos(tx))\,dx\tag 1$$

Writing $t\cos(xt)$ as $t\cos(xt)=\frac{d\sin(xt)}{dx}$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\frac{d\sin(xt)}{dx}\,dx\tag2$$

Integrating by parts the integral in $(2)$, we obtain

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin(xt)\,dx\tag3$$

Enforcing the substation $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ in $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
f(t)&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\sin(t\sin(x))\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(t\sin(x))\,dx\tag 4\\\\
&=-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(t)\right)\tag5\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 J_1(t)\tag6
\end{align}$$

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we used $(\text{P}3)$ and in going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we used $(\text{P}6)$.

Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{f(t)}{t}=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(tx)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{J_1(t)}t}$$

And we are done!